# Drag Positioning math

Tags: javascript, typescript, math

I'm trying to implement a feature where you can drag on your screen to change the Position of an Object.
Right now the object is moving similarly to the change of the mouseX.

What I want is the further down on the screen you drag your mouse, the slower the object moves.
I'm pretty bad at maths so i dont really now how to achieve that in a good way.

Right now I'm doing it like that

```
factor = Math.abs(e.deltaY)/4;
this.newX = this.currentX + (e.deltaX / factor);
```

currentX is the start X value of the object.

No idea if it is clear what i want to achieve or if i provided all information, but any help is appreciated!

Comment: I'm afraid it isn't very clear. If possible, please create a [mcve] and add it to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your arithmetics always makes step equal to 4.

Consider using some function like exponent. For example,

```
factor = Exp(- k * Abs(deltaX))
```

If you want to provide factor 1 at close distances and factor halves per every 100 pixels (I've got arbitrary reasonable values), then

```
0.5 = exp( - k * 100)
ln(0.5) = -k * 100
k = -  ln(0.5) / 100 ~= 0.007
```

note that I mean multiplicative factor:

```
factor = Exp(- 0.007 * Abs(deltaX))
this.newX = this.currentX + (e.deltaX * factor);
```

Now speed will be 1 for small distances, 0.5 for 100, 0.25 for 200, 0.125 for 300 and so on.

If you want another dependence, it is possible to find appropriate function.

Comment: Thank you! that's exactly what i was looking for!